# Why wont my image show on a javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas

Here is the code inside my constructor of this class

```
 this.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 this.canvasContext = this.canvas.getContext('2d');
 this.canvasContext.font = "45px Arial";
 this.canvas.onshow = function () {
 console.log("here!");
 window.renderer.updateDimesions();
```

Here is the method where I a unit based on its qualities. At the moment it is a prototype code. Everything works except rendering the picture. The error message is "uncaught type error: cannot read property 'drawImage' of undefined"

```
 drawUnits = function(SceneGraph,uType)
{
var aLength = window.SceneGraph.getLength();
var offset = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < aLength; i ++)
{
   

     var length = SceneGraph.get(i).getLength();
        var width = SceneGraph.get(i).getWidth();
        var price = SceneGraph.get(i).getPrice();
        var type = SceneGraph.get(i).getType();
        var description = SceneGraph.get(i).getDescription();
        var expanded = SceneGraph.get(i).getExpanded();
        console.log(length,width,price,type,description);
        if(expanded){
            this.canvasContext.font = "45px Arial"
            this.canvasContext.fillText(length + "x" + width,0, (i * 50) + 50 + offset)
            this.canvasContext.fillText(price + "$",670, (i * 50) + 50 + offset)
            this.canvasContext.beginPath();
            this.canvasContext.rect(0, (i*50) + offset, 774, 50);
            this.canvasContext.stroke();
            //row with price and size
            this.canvasContext.fillText("PICTURE",0, (i * 50 ) + 120)
            this.canvasContext.font = "15px Arial"
            this.wrapText(this.canvasContext,description,258,(i * 50)+ 70,516,20) //Html5canvastutorials.com. 2020. HTML5 Canvas Text Wrap Tutorial. [online] Available at: <https://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-wrap-text-tutorial/> [Accessed 21 December 2020].
            this.canvasContext.font = "30px Arial"
            this.canvasContext.fillText("Click van to reserve unit",258, (i * 50) + 175)
            this.canvasContext.font = "45px Arial"
            var van = new Image();
            van.src = "images/perfec1.jpg";
            van.onload = function(){
            this.canvasContext.drawImage(van,100,100);
            }
            //  this.canvasContext.fillText("VAN",650, (i * 50) + 175)
            offset = 150; // keep at end
        }
```

Comment: Code seems incomplete. Lacking some structure. Can you show the complete code?

Comment: Also add a console.log in your `onload` callback to verify the image loaded.  You should add an `onerror` callback too and log if there's an error.

Comment: I added the whole code

Comment: Also I added a console.log and the image did load.

Comment: this inside onload refer to the Image (van) object. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696200/calling-an-object-function-from-onload-event-makes-it-lose-the-context

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the onload to an event listener

```
 van.addEventListener('load', e => {
          this.canvasContext.drawImage(van,516, (i* 50) - 18);
        });
```

Comment: The event listener didn't fix this. You have fixed it by using the Arrow function expressions https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this. Another word, if you replace e => with  function() it would not work again. You could have fixed it by doing van.onload = () => { this.canvasContext.drawImage(van,516, (i* 50) - 18);} to get your original event listener method working.